# Paladin Danse randomly becomes hostile

Tags: fallout-4

I have Paladin Danse as a follower. We are out in the wasteland, a vertibird comes up and starts shooting at us. He returns fire but soon becomes hostile, and I end up dying pretty quickly. I've gone back a few saves and the same thing ends up happening. Any idea how to reset this?

I'm playing on PS4.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I added the game tag, which is the most important. Always add the tag for the game you're asking about. We usually don't include the platform tag, but I've left it on since the fact you're on a console affects the types of solutions available to you.

Comment: Do other vertibirds shoot at you? If you travel to the airport, is the rest of the brotherhood hostile? How far are you in the main quest line?

Comment: I've removed the platform tag and specified it in the body. While it may narrow down answers to relate to consoles, it does not follow the tag guidelines for the PS4. Tags are mainly for searching and filtering anyway, and this would be a somewhat inappropriate question for someone looking for only PS4 related questions.

Comment: @DCShannon Thanks for replying. I am at the stage where you have to talk to the elder BOS guy for the first time. Other vertibirds do attack me, and everyone at the Prydwen is hostile.

Comment: I would dismiss Danse as a follower (for now). Go inside to do it if you have to. Then take out the vertibird when you and Danse are far enough apart that he won't notice. Then just wander for a few in-game days doing side quests or whatever. Then try going back to the Prydwen and see if they are hostile. If they are not, go get Danse to re-join.

Answer (score 1):

If the Brotherhood are all attacking you, then the faction is currently hostile to you. This would make Danse attack you as well, as he is part of the faction.

If this is due to a quest decision, like going too far with the Institute to still be at peace with the Brotherhood, then you can't really do anything about it.

If this is due to some recent actions, like shooting at members of the faction, then it should go away after a few days. Try waiting or sleeping. You'll probably want to dismiss Danse during this time. Go back to the Prydwen afterward, and see if they still attack you. If they've stopped, then you're all good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave the area for a few days, its like this on all platforms, and since you aren't on pc there isn't much you can do via the console. So that is pretty much your best bet, at least it worked for me.